# Playing several sequences from a video uninterrupted each after other with VLC, using windows batch file

Tags: batch-file, vlc-media-player, video-playback

Running vlc player from a windows bat-file, I want to play several fragmentes from one and the same video file.

Up to now, I have this (just for demonstration purpose: playing `video_file.mp4` from 0:15 to 0:17, then 0:45 to 0:48):

```
"C:[path]vlc.exe" video_file.mp4 --start-time 15 --stop-time 17 --fullscreen --video-title-timeout=0  --play-and-exit

"C:[path]vlc.exe" video_file.mp4 --start-time 45 --stop-time 48 --fullscreen --video-title-timeout=0  --play-and-exit
```

After each fragment, the player stops with the last frame. I have to close vlc player and it reopens automatically to play the next sequence.

However, I would like it to immediately start the next sequence: how to do that?

I tried adding the timecodes for the second sequence immediately after the first one, but that does not work. Alos deleting `--play-and-exit` or replacing it with `--play-and-pause` stops the playback.

Comment: Did you tried this before ? [Do You Want VLC to Restart or Continue the Playback Where Left Off?](https://www.vlchelp.com/restart-continue-playback-ask/)

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, but it's not what I want. THis options allows to stop the video and later resume at the same time. I would like **not** to stop the video and **not** to resume at the same time, but "jump" immediately to another timecode - like playback 20 seconds here, then immediately jump 3 minutes and play another 10 seconds from there etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just give a try for this batch script and tell how does it works on your side ?

---

```bat
@echo off
set "VLCPathEXE=C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe"
set "videofile=video_file.mp4"
Call :PlayVideo "%videofile%" 20 30
Call :PlayVideo "%videofile%" 45 60
EXIT
::=================================================================================================================================================
:PlayVideo <VideoFile> <StartTime> <EndTime> <Duration to be Set>
set videofile=%~1
set /a "StartTime=%2"
Set /a "EndTime=%3"
echo STartTime : %StartTime%
echo EndTime   : %EndTime%
Set /a Duration=%EndTime% - %StartTime%+1
Start "" "%VLCPathEXE%" "%videofile%" --start-time %StartTime% --stop-time %EndTime% --fullscreen --video-title-timeout=0 --one-instance vlc://quit
Timeout /T %Duration% /Nobreak>nul & Taskkill /im "vlc.exe" /F
Exit /B
::=================================================================================================================================================
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the path to vlc is not found, so it does not run. could not find out how to change the script to include the path: `C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe`

Comment: OK, now, changing `do Set "VLCPathEXE=%%j"` with `do Set "VLCPathEXE=C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe"`, it works - however, I have to add (copy) another line `Timeout /T 3 /Nobreak>nul & taskkill /im "vlc.exe" /F` at the end, otherwise VLC keeps playing the last sequence in loop. So this now comes close to what I was looking for, thanks! Only thing remains that VLC closes to be re-opened immediately to play the next sequence. Would be nice if it would contu^inue to play in the same instance/window, without closing/reopening a new window.

Comment: What does the `Timeout /T 3 ` part stand for? I see I have to adapt this if I change start- and end-time. It seems I must adapt this to the length of the sequence between start- and end-time, right? Can't it be automatically set to the length defined by start/end-time?

Comment: @Babel yep your best is to define the start and end time and calculate the `Duration= EndTime-StartTime` and set it to Timeout

Comment: @Babel Please check my last edit.

Comment: Great! This is 90% of what I was looking for and works well. Only the part to keep open the same instance of VLC is open. Still, it's a working solution, thanks.